# Can we run Mobile Blazor Bindings project in web browser?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-blazor

I know, the Mobile Blazor Bindings(MBB) are hybrid apps for targeting cross-platform native rendering. Can we run the same MBB project in a web browser or do we need to maintain two different projects for web and hybrid apps? I hope, there should be a way to reuse the web app in MBB. Please share your suggestions for this to create a shared source to reusing a single app to render both web and hybrid apps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/unified-ui-mobile-blazor-bindings-preview-5/

I'm a newbie to MBB projects and are trying to do the same as you. Any feedback would be appreciated ;)